# How to fix audio after December 2020 update

Tags: raspbian, audio, pulseaudio

I recently updated my Pi4 to the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS, following all the steps to change the audio software to pulseaudio - from the instructions on the website. https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/new-raspberry-pi-os-release-december-2020/ Upon rebooting I discovered I could no longer listen to audio through either the HDMI or the AV jack. I can only listen to audio now via bluetooth. Has anyone else had this problem or does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks

Edit:
I'm now having a similiar problem on a new sd card with ubuntu 20.04. I've tried removing pulseaudio but that hasn't helped. Anyone know how i can fix this?

Comment: There is this thread https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=293471 not sure if it will help but looks like some others are having issues.

Comment: I can't believe that the dark times of `.asoundrc` will finally be over soon!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure HDMI is selected as default output in Sound & Video -> PulseAudio Volume Control settings. You have to click on the green checkmark with "set as fallback" tooltip in the screenshot below:

[image]

If that doesn't help, or you don't want to keep Pulse at all, remove `pulseaudio`, reboot, and your system should be back to plain ALSA. You can configure ALSA sound from command line with `alsamixer`.

If you want Pulse back, or didn't get it due to packages being held back, can force the update with `sudo apt-get upgrade raspberrypi-ui-mods`.

Comment: @Stefano, thanks for confirming it worked for you too.

Comment: Strange, I can't find "PulseAudio Volume Control" in my Pi's Sound & Video menu. The OS is certainly up-to-date and I've installed and upgraded raspberrypi-ui-mods.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was that `raspberrypi-ui-mods` had been held back and it needed to be force updated. You can confirm this by checking if there is a message about it being held back when you run `sudo apt upgrade`.

Upgrade `raspberrypi-ui-mods` by running `sudo apt-get upgrade raspberrypi-ui-mods`.

If you remove pulseaudio, apart from this not being recommended, it will only end up being installed again when you apt upgrade, so that is pointless.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `apt` will not reinstall a removed package with an `apt upgrade`.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but at least on raspberry pi OS it ended up being reinstalled immediately on `apt upgrade`.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't run other commands in between, which *can* install additional packages, such as `apt dist-upgrade`, `apt -f install`, `apt upgrade pkg_name`, etc? I must admit I didn't test it though, I personally like Pulse and find it crazy that Pi OS had to wait until 2020 to make use of it.

Comment: Yup, pretty certain. I also was surprised.