# No HDMI audio when logged in as a new user

Tags: audio, hdmi, user

Sound over HDMI works fine when I login as the default user `pi`.

I created a new user named for example `user1`

If I login as this user, no sound plays through hdmi.

I then added this user to most groups the `pi` user belongs to, such as audio, video, etc except sudo and pi as I do not want this new user to have root access.

Sound over HDMI is still not working (works fine through a usb dongle though, I don't have a 3.5mm jack as this is a pi400)

If I open a terminal, do a `su pi` and then `aplay somesoundorother.wav` I get a sound output as expected. However the exact same command as `user1` does not output any sound

What is the difference between the defaut `pi` user and the new user that would cause this behaviour ? Is this a bug ?

Thanks.

Edit: Here is the output of `aplay -L`

```
    null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
output
input
sysdefault:CARD=b1
    bcm2835 HDMI 1, bcm2835 HDMI 1
    Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=b1,DEV=0
    bcm2835 HDMI 1, bcm2835 HDMI 1
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=b1,DEV=0
    bcm2835 HDMI 1, bcm2835 HDMI 1
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=b1,DEV=0
    bcm2835 HDMI 1, bcm2835 HDMI 1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=b1,DEV=0
    bcm2835 HDMI 1, bcm2835 HDMI 1
    Hardware device with all software conversions
usbstream:CARD=b1
    bcm2835 HDMI 1
    USB Stream Output
sysdefault:CARD=Headphones
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Hardware device with all software conversions
usbstream:CARD=Headphones
    bcm2835 Headphones
    USB Stream Output
```

also if I use the following command, the sound works :
`aplay -D sysdefault /usr/share/scratch/Media/Sounds/Instruments/StringAccent.wav`

How can I can make this "sysdefault" device the default?

Comment: *"I then added this user to most groups the pi user belongs to"* -> Just in case:  Those changes won't be in effect for existing logins by that user, only future ones.

Comment: Yes, I rebooted multiple times while doing all of this so I don’t think that’s the issue

Comment: Check the output options in the GUI - Pi seems to mess around with these that other users do not...

Comment: Where exactly in the gui ? if I right click on the loudspeaker icon in the top bar it shows HDMI wiith a green check mark next to it.

Comment: Have you tried editing the ~/.asoundrc file?

Comment: Yes. I copied the working one from the pi user to the new user’s home folder, without success. I also tried changing devices and such but could not get a working configuration

Answer (score 1):

If you're using raspbian you could try this:

In the top right, there is  a volume icon, if you right click that you should probably see the HDMI option, make sure there's a green check mark next to it.

[image: HDMI Option]

Comment: Yes there is a green check mark next to the hdmi entry.

Answer (score 1):

See if you can set the default audio sink device in Pulse Audio Volume Control settings, as described in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118983/33476). Pulse settings are user-specific, so this has to be done for every user you create.