# no sound in terminal python at all

Tags: python

there are no sound in python terminal at all.

But there are sound in in youtube.com, and (play sound from terminal command and play speech09022021212808.mp3)

here is a example:

```
from text_to_speech import speak 

speak("hello")
```

the text_to_speech will generate a mp3 file and it try to play the file (But no sound at all)

Info:
Raspberry pi, Python 3.7.3

I can do the same in windows 10 and there are sound.

Can you help me out?

Comment: Did you [configure](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118983/33476) the default audio device? Is there an API to select the audio device in Python?

Comment: still nothing, i have try to this command: alsamixer / but still no sound in python3 at all. but sound in youtube.com